# Not Able to Send Mail Using PHP?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to send a mail through core Php, I have created a file `email.php` and included `PHPMailer_v5.1` in it.. here is my php code,

```
<?php if($_POST){
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$comments = $_REQUEST['comments'] ;
$phone = $_POST['telephone'] ;
$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->Host = "localhost";               
$mail->From = "scorpion.schizo@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName  =  "Showket";
$mail->AddAddress("manusurya9139@gmail.com");


$mail->Subject = "Feedback form results";
$mail->Body="
    Name: $name
    Email: $email
    Telephone: $telephone
    Comments: $comments";

$mail->WordWrap = 50;

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo 'Message was not sent.';
   echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
   echo 'Thank you for your feedback.';
}
} 
?>
```

when i post this form it gives me the right message **Thank you for your feedback.** but i didnt recieve the message..do i need to configure anything else ?

Comment: Check the "Spam" folder in your e-mail account

Comment: @Showket: are you sure the SMTP server is working properly on your server

Comment: Gmail will definitely flag that as spam.  Sending to a gmail address from a gmail address with a non-gmail server?

Comment: have you looked at the logs of your mail server ?

Comment: How can i check my SMTP server ? if it is working or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting Gmail as your SMTP

```
<?php if($_POST){ 
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ; 
$comments = $_REQUEST['comments'] ; 
$phone = $_POST['telephone'] ; 
$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ; 

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP(); // send via SMTP
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465"; // SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "scorpion.schizo@gmail.com"; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "password"; // SMTP password

$mail->Host = "localhost";                
$mail->From = "scorpion.schizo@gmail.com"; 
$mail->FromName  =  "Showket"; 
$mail->AddAddress("manusurya9139@gmail.com"); 

$mail->Subject = "Feedback form results"; 
$mail->Body=" 
Name: $name 
Email: $email 
Telephone: $telephone 
Comments: $comments"; 

$mail->WordWrap = 50; 

if(!$mail->Send()) 
{ 
    echo 'Message was not sent.'; 
    echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo; 
} 
else 
{ 
    echo 'Thank you for your feedback.'; 
} 
}  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Run "sendmail -bp" to check if there is anything in the queue. Also, check the email folder for the user that your webserver is running under to see if you have had any undeliverable notifications.